# eror when retrieve createdby field in crm using plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I try to retrieve the createdby field when I create a cases with a plugin, but the first retrieval fails, and the second and subsequent retrieval are successful. And then when I logged out and login with other user the first retrieval fails (retrieve result is the user before i change the user), and the second and subsequent retrieval are successful.

here is the code i write :

```
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProv)
    {
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProv.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        IOrganizationServiceFactory servicefac = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProv.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        IOrganizationService service = servicefac.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
        ITracingService trace = (ITracingService)serviceProv.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            Entity ent = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            if (ent.LogicalName != "incident")
                return;

            QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression("incident");
            string[] cols1 = { "createdby" };
            qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);

            EntityCollection ec = service.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
            foreach (Entity act in ec.Entities)
            {
                created = act. GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("createdby").Name;
            }

            if (created == "CRM SNA")
            {
                created = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                //here is the autonumber code
                created = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

What I want to make is an autonumber plugin, when cases are created by "CRM SNA" then the autonumber must not run, when cases are created by other users the autonumber will run.

How to make the first retrieve successful? and did not retrieve the user before?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your plugin runs in the Pre-Create step. CreatedBy and CreatedOn are not available in this step (probably because the record is not saved yet).

If you are just trying to get the user that executed the action that fired the plugin, use context.InitiatingUserId. You could also look into the documentation for the WhoAmI request.

Hope that helps!